# "$ is not defined" error on resize

Tags: jquery

I have this code that I used many times :

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  //mycode
});
```

But this time I've got a "$ is not defined" error, can you help me to understand why (I have other function on this website using $(window) that are working : $(window).scrollTop() is working well) ?

I did try to use :

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
//blabla 
});
```

and my jQuery import is like that :

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js';
script.type = 'text/javascript';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try :

```
//jQuery import
script.onload = function() {
  $(document).ready(function () { 
    //blabla 
  });
};
```